# Ffmpeg segmenting syntax

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to break long video files (circa 60mins) with the following requirements:
30sec chunks (fairly exact chunks, no frame loss between chunks)
Transcoded to html 5 compatible video
Filenames in time code format eg first chunk 00:00:00 second chunk 00:00:30 etc (it would be great if first chunk time could be specified by this would be the cherry on top!)

So far the closest working script I got was

```
    ffmpeg -i VID_20130417_140328_555.mp4 -s 480x360 -map 0 -keyint_min 10 -vcodec libx264 -g 60 -vb 500000 -strict experimental -acodec libfaac -f ssegment -segment_list out.list out%03d.ts
```

This segments the file into the correct format but I can't control duration or naming.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refer to `-segment_time` in the [segment muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) docs.

Comment: Also, you should always include the complete console output, you don't need `-strict experimental`, and `-f ssegment` looks like a typo. [SO] is off-topic, so I voted for migration to [SU].